# ReadInt() returning absurd values

Tags: java, file, int, persistence

I have a method that stores an int in a .dat file (among other things) later I try to retrieve that in with a different method and it gives an absurd value. For example if I try to store a 1 the other method retrieves 484449. I'm new to Java so if this is somehow normal please explain.

Method that writes int:

```
public static int fromText (String textRefference, String binaryRefference, 
            boolean overwrite, String countRefference){

        if(!(new File(binaryRefference).exists()))overwrite = true;
        BufferedReader input;
        ObjectOutputStream output;
        ObjectInputStream binaryInput;
        ObjectInputStream countStreamI;
        ObjectOutputStream countStreamO;
        int count = 0;

        try{
            input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textRefference));
            String[] data = null;
            int oldCount = 0;
            if(!overwrite){
                countStreamI = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(countRefference));
                binaryInput = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(binaryRefference));
                oldCount = countStreamI.readInt();
                data = new String[oldCount];
                int i;
                for(i = 0;i < oldCount; i++){

                    data[i] = binaryInput.readUTF();

                }
                countStreamI.close();
            }

            countStreamO = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(countRefference));
            output = new 
                    ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(binaryRefference));

            String sentinel = input.readLine();
            String[] data2 = new String[1500];
            while(!sentinel.equalsIgnoreCase("end")){

                System.out.println(sentinel + "   has been recorded");
                data2[count] = sentinel;
                sentinel = input.readLine();
                count++;

            }

            count += oldCount;
            countStreamO.writeInt(count);

            if(!overwrite){

                int i;
                for(i = 0; i < oldCount;i++){

                    output.writeUTF(data[i]);

                }

            }

            int i = 0;
            for(; i < count + oldCount;i++){

                output.writeUTF(data2[i]);

            }

            output.flush();
            countStreamO.flush();
            countStreamO.close();
            output.close();
            input.close();

        }

        catch(Exception e){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            e.printStackTrace();
            in.nextLine();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return count;
    }'
```

And the function retrieving it:

```
public static String[] pullStrings(String file, String countReferrence, boolean print){

        String[] data = null;

        try{

            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            int count = input.readInt();
            data = new String[count];
            int i = 0;
            String string;
            for(;i < count; i++){

                string = input.readUTF();
                if(print)System.out.println(string);
                data[i] = string;

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "\n\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\n hit ENTER to exit.");
            in.nextLine(); 
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return data;

    }
```

And the text file:

```
data!!!

end
```

Comment: Your question is essentially, `"why is the code that I'm not showing you not working?"`. Please fix this by creating and posting your [mcve].

Comment: Always post your code and your error if there is an error. A simple description is not enough to help you

Comment: can you share the functions with us? Without code examples it's really hard to help you.

Comment: "I'm new to Java so if this is somehow normal please explain." -- Are there any computer languages you have heard of where this is somehow normal?

Comment: I posted the code. And @azurefrog some of the things Java does are foreign to me coming from c#. So I figured there might be some type of conversion I had to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This strange number you're getting, 484449, is actually the result of reading four bytes: 00 07 64 61.

Where did those bytes come from?  Well, for some reason, you chose to send `count` to **a different file,** using `countStreamO.writeInt(count);`.  So when your retrieval code executes `input.readInt()`, it's expecting to find a count in the same file, but you never wrote it there.

Instead, you sent the count to a different file, then proceeded to write each string to the main data file using `output.writeUTF(data[i])` and `output.writeUTF(data2[i])`.

What does writeUTF actually do?  Well, the documentation for ObjectOutputStream.writeUTF doesn't say much about it, except that the method is mandated by the DataOutput interface.  The [documentation for DataOutput.writeUTF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeUTF-java.lang.String-) is pretty informative, though:

> Writes two bytes of length information to the output stream, followed by the modified UTF-8 representation of every character in the string `s`.

So you never wrote your `count` value to the file, but you did send the string "data!!!" to it.  And now we know that writeUTF first writes the byte length of that string (after converting it to modified UTF-8) followed by the modified UTF-8 bytes themselves.

In this case, your String consists entirely of ASCII characters, which, when encoded in modified UTF-8 (or real UTF-8, for that matter), take up one byte each, with no encoding required.  So the string requires 7 bytes, one for each character.

Meaning, the writeUTF method wrote two bytes for the byte length (00 07) followed by seven bytes for the characters (64 61 74 61 21 21 21).

Which means the first four bytes in the file are 00 07 64 61.  You're trying to read them as 32-bit int, so you're getting 0x00076461, or 484449.

Your code is far more complicated than it needs to be.  That complexity makes it difficult to see small problems like this one.  Also, some documentation would have made it clear what your code should be doing.  It looks like you realized by the time you got around to writing the retrieval code that you didn't need a separate file for the count, but you never went back and updated the code that writes the data to accommodate the improvement.

I don't know if your data file needs to adhere to an externally specified format, but if it doesn't, you can easily accomplish your task by doing away with counts entirely, and doing away with readUTF and writeUTF.  Instead, you can simply serialize a String array:

```
String[] allData = new String[data.length + data2.length];
System.arraycopy(data, 0, allData, 0, data.length);
System.arraycopy(data2, 0, allData, data.length, data2.length);

try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
        new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(binaryReference)))) {
    out.write(allData);
}
```

The length is part of the array object's state, so it is included in the serialized output.

Reading it is even easier:

```
String[] data;
try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
        new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(file)))) {
    data = (String[]) in.readObject();
}
```